# Open link in newtab missing from context menu

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

The new tab is missing from the browser context menu in Nuxt.js projects. I need to make sure my clients can freely open links in a new tab.
How can I add this feature globally in Nuxt.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the `v-btn` component with the `link` prop? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props-link

If the generated HTML is not an actual `<a href="blog">Go to blog</a>`, you will not have it on the context menu.
You could inspect in the DOM and see how it is.

Buttons are for **actions**, links for **navigation**.
If it's a link, should be able to open it in a new tab, if it's a button with something like `@click="$router.push('/blog')"`, this won't work with the context menu.